# Change position of a IBOutlet in Swift

Tags: button, swift, position, iboutlet

So i have this button:

```
@IBOutlet var bouton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

And i want to change is position

But the buton doesn't seems to have a position property like for SKSpriteNode

So is there a way to change is position ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to programmatically change the position of any view, you can use this:

```
button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the button with  myButton.frame.origin if you are using autolayout. So you must add constraints. For example:

`let buttonConstraintY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: youButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
  self.view.addConstraint(buttonConstraintY)`